# How can I view the indexes I have set up in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have some indexes set up on the table `entries` and I want to view them / list them. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
show index from entries;
```

details : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html

Another way is make use of information_schema.STATISTICS

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.STATISTICS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='{$db}' AND TABLE_NAME='entries';
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to ajreal's answer:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM entries
```

which I think is the correct answer here, there is another useful command that I think is worth mentioning in case you don't already know it:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE entries
```

This shows the entire command you would need to recreate the table structure, including the indexes. It also shows the result in a more familiar format because it is similar to how you might have typed it when you created it. I think it is worth knowing about both commands as sometimes one can be more useful, and sometimes the other.

Comment: this actually came in use later

Answer (score 1):

Query is as below:

```
SHOW index FROM entries;
```

You can go through this link for more details :-

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html

Answer (score 0):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html